# this line will be used to open a file in windowforms and how this line will be used?

Tags: c#

I didn't  understand this line. Anyone explain brefil'y how this line works in windows forms.

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: Did you try and debug what happens?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The code provided has nothing to do with Windows Forms, by the way. It's .NET.

Comment: Copy that line of code.  Then paste into your favorite internet search tool.  Before you press enter, change all the punctuation (the dots and the parentheses) to spaces and remove the semi-colon (you will get _"system environment getfolderpath environment specialfolder personal"_).  Then search and read what you find

Comment: @Flydog even just pasting the code as-is into Google hits the right documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

In any normal case, it just gets your *MyDocuments* path

[Environment.GetFolderPath Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets the path to the system special folder that is identified by the
>   specified enumeration.

[Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Specifies enumerated constants used to retrieve directory paths to
>   system special folders.
>
> - **Personal** : The directory that serves as a common repository for documents. This member is equivalent to MyDocuments.